# remote build to raspberry pi via Visual Studio 2017

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2017, raspberry-pi3

Over the past few days I have been setting up my Raspberry pi 3. I set up the SSH connection between my desktop and the pi and used putty to create the SSH keys and got the connection working but now I've run into a problem. I'm trying to connect Visual Studio 2017 to the pi but every time I try to connect it gives me this error, 'An error occurred using private key '/file/path'. Please make sure you are using an open-ssh format compatible key'. Anyone know how to fix this?